# jQuery datatable sort and order from selected option column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable and I need to filter and sort inside a cell that contains html select inputs by the text in the selected option `<select><option selected="selected">**text to filter**</option></select>`.

So I need to search the rows in the table that contain a td that contains a select box where I've selected the option with the text used for the search.

So if in a cell I choose the option with **"text to filter"** text that row must be visible.
Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: my table contains a column with a select box per row and the user can select an option in each row. Than I need to filter the table by the value selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use custom filtering, I think. 
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

See this jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/DYyLd/

Search for "x" and only the row with "x" selected will show.  Change the selected option, and the search will find it/omit it as appropriate.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
        var nodes = $(oTable.fnGetNodes(iDataIndex));
        var selItem = nodes.find('select').val();

        // This is basic.  You should split the string and look
        // for each individual substring
        var filterValue = $('div.dataTables_filter input').val();

        return (selItem.indexOf(filterValue) !== -1);
    }
);
```

Also, I added this:

```
$('select').click(function() { $('#myTable').dataTable().fnDraw(); });
```

which redraws the table when any of the selects are changed - that way, they are re-filtered.

As commented in the example, my search function is very basic, only looking to see if the selected item in the select box contains the exact text in the search field, case sensitive.  You would almost certainly want to split the string by spaces, and search for each substring in selItem.  Also notice this method doesn't search other the column(s) - it only looks in the column with the select box.  You may want to search the other columns as well.

Comment: hi, thank you for interesting in my problem. That solution seems to be the way, the only problem is that the "selectBox[0].value" seems to retrive always the value of the first option or the value pre-selected by code (with selected="selected"). so, if I change my selected option in real time the filter will always filter by the original value. There is a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, it appears the aData parameter passed to the filtering function uses the data as it was at create time.  I've modified it to pull the actual data from the DataTable nodes.

Comment: how would you go about filtering not only the inputs but also table-wide ?

Comment: It still works for me.  Enter either x, y, or z in the filter box, and the appropriate rows will show.  What is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Found the best solution for this situation, follow this link and example:

https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

Adding to `column: []`:

```
    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" }
```

and:

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('select', td).val();
    } );
}
```

Comment: I've found that this sorts on the selection option value, not the displayed text. Trying to return text() instead of val() doesn't work. Still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a column in a datatable based on a select, you can use the example from datatable site (https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html), but you have to change it a little bit to enable sorting on the text rather than on the value. In the example it says to add:

```
{ "orderDataType": "dom-select" }
```

and

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map(function(td,i ) {
        return $('select', td).val();
    });
}
```

This will sort the column to the value of the options.
To sort to text value I changed the function above a little bit:

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map(function(td,i ) {
        //return $('select', td).val(); // <== the original solution
        var idx = $('select', td)[0].selectedIndex;
        var elm = $('select', td)[0][idx];
        // elm is the HTML element
        var s = elm.text;
        s = s.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
        // s contains the string value of the option
        return s;
    });
}
```

Now the column will be sorted on the visible value when a user clicks on the column header.

I hope it wil work for you as well!