# Search and sort based on the value of the select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like my whole table to be editable. Thus all my data is placed inside an input, like that :

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control dnsinput" type="text" value="{{ line.host }}" />
</td>
```

the problem is that the ordering/search of datatables is not searching inside that input.
I had the idea to do a span hidden with the data inside it, which solved the search problem, but not the filtering one. Felt like this was a bad idea overall.

I feel like the best way would be to modify datatables's default behaviour, but I didn't find what I wanted in the docs.

Basically to shorten this up, I would like :
to put in every cell, an input containing the data (that I already did) and that the ordering and searching functionnalities of datatables go and search inside those inputs.

Has anyone ever had to do such a thing? If yes, is there a "standard way" of doing so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columnDefs`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to target a specific column using zero-based index in [`targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) option and [`render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to return selected value during searching (`type === 'filter'`) or sorting (`type === 'order'`).

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
      { 
         targets: [2, 3], 
         render: function(data, type, full, meta){
            if(type === 'filter' || type === 'sort'){
               var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
               var td = api.cell({row: meta.row, column: meta.col}).node();
               data = $('select, input', td).val();
            }

            return data;
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

Also you need to invalidate cell data once data changes as shown below (according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27860934/3549014)).

```
$('tbody select, tbody input', table.table().node()).on('change', function(){
     table.row($(this).closest('tr')).invalidate();
});
```

> **DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
   
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      columnDefs: [
         { 
           targets: [2, 3], 
           render: function(data, type, full, meta){
              if(type === 'filter' || type === 'sort'){
                 var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
                 var td = api.cell({row: meta.row, column: meta.col}).node();
                 data = $('select, input', td).val();
              }
              
              return data;
           }
        }
      ]
   });
  
   $('tbody select, tbody input', table.table().node()).on('change', function(){
       table.row($(this).closest('tr')).invalidate();   
   });
  
   // For testing purposes: make sure newly added rows also work
   $('#btn-add').on('click', function(){
      table.row.add(['John Dow', 'Janitor', '<select><option selected>Edinburgh</option><option>New York</option><option>San Francisco</option></select>', '<input type="text" value="23">', '2011/07/25', '$5,000']).draw(false);
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>jQuery DataTables</title>  
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
<p><button id="btn-add">Add row</button>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
  <td>System Architect</td>
  <td><select><option>Edinburgh</option><option selected>New York</option><option>San Francisco</option></select></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="61"></td>
  <td>2011/04/25</td>
  <td>$3,120</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Garrett Winters</td>
  <td>Director</td>
  <td><select><option selected>Edinburgh</option><option>New York</option><option>San Francisco</option></select></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="63"></td>
  <td>2011/07/25</td>
  <td>$5,300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ashton Cox</td>
  <td>Technical Author</td>
  <td><select><option>Edinburgh</option><option>New York</option><option selected>San Francisco</option></select></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="66"></td>
  <td>2009/01/12</td>
  <td>$4,800</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I opted for the first solution, which works wonder. Did a few changes to adapt for my use case, it's just perfect. Thanks for your complete answer, hope it can help people having the same issue I had!

Comment: @Enjoyted, I corrected my code because it didn't work once the option has been changed.

Comment: Yes I saw that, I figured I would fix it later on. But you read into my minds!
However I had an error on every change, which was caused by a wrong behaviour of my datatables library (esp on Invilidate() function) ! see here : https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/623

Comment: @Enjoyted, I reported the issue [#623](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/623) you've mentioned and it has been corrected, that is why my demo uses 1.10.7 which doesn't have it. There is another bug I found, see [#643](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/643), because I would rather invalidate cell than the row with `table.cell($(this).closest('td')).invalidate();`.