# Search within input and select

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable set up in an application where the rows contain input fields and I have sort and filter the tables based on the text values of the input fields. I managed to get sorting working correctly but I cannot for the life of me get search to work. I think the problem is related to the fact that the table is generated and populated dynamically by another JavaScript that runs prior to datatables being called on it.

Here is the JavaScript so far:

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column */
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order["dom-text"] = function  ( settings, col )
    {
        return this.api().column( col, {order:"index"} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
            return $("input", td).val();
        } );
    }

    /* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column, parsed as numbers */
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order["dom-text-numeric"] = function  ( settings, col )
    {
        return this.api().column( col, {order:"index"} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
            return $("input", td).val() * 1;
        } );
    }

    /* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order["dom-select"] = function  ( settings, col )
    {
        return this.api().column( col, {order:"index"} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
            return $("select", td).val();
        } );
    }


        $(document).ready(function() {

        var table =  $("#service_group0").DataTable({
                "searching": true,
                "ordering":  true,
                "columns": [
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: \'html\' },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select",type: \'html\' },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text" , type: \'string\'},
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: \'string\' },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: \'string\'},
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric"},
                   { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: \'date\'},
                    null,
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric"},
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-select" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: \'string\' },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: \'string\' },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: \'date\'},
                    null,
                    null
                ],
                initComplete:   function () {
                    this.api().columns().every( function () {
                        var column = this;
                         if(column.index() == 5){
                            var select = $("<select id=\'strength_search\'></select>")
                                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty());
                                var strength_hidden = document.getElementById("strength_hidden").value;
                                select.append(strength_hidden);
                        }
                        else if(column.index() == 6){
                             var select = $("<select id=\'dose_search\'></select>")
                                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty());
                                var dose_hidden = document.getElementById("dose_hidden").value;
                                select.append(dose_hidden);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

There is simply to much html to paste here so I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q715LncL/12/

If you go to the jsfiddle and type stuff into the empty text fields then go to the search box and try to filter based on something you typed in it always returns no results. How can I get it to filter on the changes made to the live inputs?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom filter function that checks the values of the input boxes, DataTables converts the HTML to strings and you can't recover the live value from them, so you would have to do something like this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
      var searchTerm = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
      var $row = $('.dataTable tbody tr').eq(dataIndex);

      if(!searchTerm) {
        return true;
      }

      return $row.find('td input').filter(function() {
        return ~$(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      }).size();
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q715LncL/14/

Comment: Thanks Ill look at  this, btw your js fiddle does'nt seem to work for me. If I put test into one of the brand name fields and abc into the other then type test into the search box it does'nt find the row.

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columnDefs`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to target a specific column using zero-based index in [`targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) option and [`render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to return selected value during searching (`type === 'filter'`) or sorting (`type === 'order'`).

```
columnDefs: [
   { 
      targets: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 
      render: function(data, type, full, meta){
         if(type === 'filter' || type === 'sort'){
            var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
            var td = api.cell({row: meta.row, column: meta.col}).node();
            data = $('select, input', td).val();
         }

         return data;
      }
   }
]
```

Also you need to invalidate cell data once data changes as shown below (according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27860934/3549014)).

```
$('tbody select, tbody input', table.table().node()).on('change', function(){
     table.row($(this).closest('tr')).invalidate();
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q715LncL/19/) for code and demonstration.

> **NOTES**

I have commented code that causes JavaScript errors because of the non-existing elements.

Comment: Thanks this has helped a lot and seems to work for the most part but when I use it in my actual application if I load in rows with values in the input fields it seems to clear them. Im not sure I fully understand how your code works. When table is generated and populated dynamically by the other script some of the rows will already have data in them so it need to work with both and allow sorting with live and existing date in the input fields.

Comment: @user794846, you're right, it doesn't work with newly added rows for some reason. I need to research it and will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks have been struggling with this all morning and not getting very far

Comment: Sorry its not newly added rows its rows that are added that have the input fields already populated with values. It blanks them out.