# JQuery Datatables sorting a select inside a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10.12 and JQuery 1.12.3

I got a problem with sorting a column that have dropdown list inside it

I am using the multi select filter.

All is working fine, prob is that it can't sort the column including the select (that has selected="selected" option) probably because of the value of the option tag in the multi_select that I don't know how to fill

So how could I achieve a search inside the td, maybe with regex, finding those selected option ?

Comment: do you want column search functionality for data table?

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html like this

Comment: Hi @DipakThoke, I am already using this and that's working good for others columns. My problem off of this system is with a dropdown inside a column !

Comment: can you give the js fiddle link of efforts you have taken uptil now  with dummy data. Thanks

Comment: @DipakThoke Yes, there the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zkugnpq5. As you can see the column Status don't get sorted on click. Neither with the multi_filter_select method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You can use [`columnDefs`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to target a specific column using zero-based index in [`targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) option and [`render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to return selected value during searching (`type === 'filter'`) or sorting (`type === 'order'`).

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
      { 
         targets: [0,1,2,3], 
         render: function(data, type, full, meta){
            if(type === 'filter' || type === 'sort'){
               var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
               var td = api.cell({row: meta.row, column: meta.col}).node();
               data = $('select, input', td).val();
            }

            return data;
         }
      }
   ],
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

The code above uses values of `option` elements to determine value to sort/search. However in your updated example, you're using numeric IDs as values.

To use text of `option` instead, use modified code shown below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
      { 
         targets: [0,1,2,3], 
         render: function(data, type, full, meta){
            if(type === 'filter' || type === 'sort'){
               var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
               var td = api.cell({row: meta.row, column: meta.col}).node();
               var $input = $('select, input', td);
               if($input.length && $input.is('select')){
                  data = $('option:selected', $input).text();
               } else {                   
                  data = $input.val();
               }
            }

            return data;
         }
      }
   ],
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

Also you need to invalidate cell data once data changes as shown below (according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27860934/3549014)).

```
$('tbody select, tbody input', table.table().node()).on('change', function(){
     table.row($(this).closest('tr')).invalidate();
});
```

#### DEMO

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/zkugnpq5/3/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Hi @Gyrocode.com, I know this question was answered many time ago, I recently used it as solution too, however, when I implement this solution for select input, the on change event never fires for all select input elements, how can I make they work again by keeping this solution?

Comment: The code at https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html also works for this, though to sort on the displayed text rather that the value (which may be an int that has nothing to do with the correct order for displayed text), replace return $('select', td).val(); with return $('option:selected', td).text();   I was able to figure this out thanks to your answer. ;)