# jQuery Datatables sorting select elements without restrict on change event (Not firing)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

Im actually implementing jquery datatables plugin to sort and search in tables, in in order to sort columns with select elements (dropdownlist) I had to implement this solution given here:[JQuery Datatables sorting a select inside a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238819/jquery-datatables-sorting-a-select-inside-a-column), which is:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({columnDefs: [
  { 
     targets: [0,1,2,3], 
     render: function(data, type, full, meta){
        if(type === 'filter' || type === 'sort'){
           var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
           var td = api.cell({row: meta.row, column: meta.col}).node();
           var $input = $('select, input', td);
           if($input.length && $input.is('select')){
              data = $('option:selected', $input).text();
           } else {                   
              data = $input.val();
           }
        }

        return data;
     }
  }   ],});
```

Actually this code is working good, however the onchange event for those select elements are never fired. So my question is how can I modify this code to make the on change event works for all select elements in the columns?

Comment: `$(elem).trigger("change")` is how you can [programmatically trigger event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). The better way to do it is to create a function that you call from your change handler as well as anywhere else.

Comment: @mhodges you probably did not understand my question, I dint say I dont have a function to be called from the on change, I have the function in my jquery code but it never gets colled, if I comment this block: if($input.length && $input.is('select')){
              data = $('option:selected', $input).text();
           } else {                   
              data = $input.val();
           }, the onchange starts working again

Comment: Can you post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? There is not enough code here to diagnose the issue. If you comment out the if/else, data will return undefined each time. I want to see what your HTML and what your change handler look like

Comment: You're right, I meant when I comment the whole (render:...) all onchange events work again, let me complete the sample, you might get a better idea. Thank you

Comment: @mhodges Please take a look on this code I put [here:](https://jsfiddle.net/poyson1/xgy3eby3/5/), here it is working fine because I'm adding the class in the select elements directly on the html,  but in my code which es asp.net when the page runs, in the client side the class is removed then the onchange does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using a different selector? i.e. `$("table select").on("change", ...)`

Comment: @mhodges Something very weird was happening, for some reason that I still don't know all jQuery codes inside the script tab were not firing when utilizing the above function but when I added a  $(document).ready(function () {...}); and put all the code in it, it worked; when I don't use the above function this is not needed!