# datatables search ignore html

Tags: javascript, datatable

Can I filter data in datatables based on plaintext values?

My rows in datatable looks like:

```
<tr data-position="1">
<td>1</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="1-text_view" value="SOME PLAINTEXT">
</td>
<td>
    <textarea name="1-textarea">SOME PLAINTEXT</textarea>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="1-macro" value="SOME PLAINTEXT">
</td>
<td>
    <div class='radio'>
        <input name='1-show_if' type='radio' class='flat' checked value='1'> SOME PLAINTEXT
    </div>
    <div class='radio'>
        <input name='1-show_if' type='radio' class='flat'>
        <select class='show-if-id' name='1-show_if-id'>
            <option>SOME PLAINTEXT</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
<td><i class='fa fa-arrows handler'></i><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></td>
</tr>
```

And search plugin doesn't work. It is trying to filter something, but I need to strip html when searching and support searching in value="" attribute.
Is this possible some way?

Comment: Which search plugin you have ?

Comment: datatables.net default search

Comment: See this -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852497/jquery-datatables-search-within-input-and-select/27860934#27860934** (mine, but the only valid answer I know of, it is more tricky than you would expect!) treat `<textarea>` as `<input>` ...