# Get Datatables cell value that is input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, input, datatables

I'm generating a DataTable with a javascript data source. The *data* is returned from an ajax call to nodejs which queries SQL Server DB table and returns 2 columns, both numerical data. I'm adding 2 more columns to hold input fields, with default value of 0, for the user to enter numbers that will increase/decrease the values found in ColumnA/B.

```
$('#mytable').DataTable( {
    "data": data,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "ColumnA", "defaultContent": "NA" },
        { "data": "ColumnB", "defaultContent": "NA" },
        { "data": undefined, "defaultContent": '<input type="text" value="0" size="10"/>'},
        { "data": undefined, "defaultContent": '<input type="text" value="0" size="10"/>'}
    ]
});
```

This renders just fine and I can modify the text in the input field in the cell.
There is a separate input field outside the table that the user can click to 'submit changes', which calls a javascript function that will read those input fields of the table. However, I cannot figure out how to get them. Using:

```
var aTable = $('#mytable').DataTable();
var colAchange = atable.cell(0, 2).data();
var colBchange = atable.cell(0, 3).data();
```

Both colA/Bchange vars just have the 'input type="text" ...' html text, not the value of the input field. This does make sense, but I cannot find the right way to read the value of the input field.
At one time I had read in the Datatables docs that you can add 'meta' data to the row data. Do I need to do that to get an "id" on that  element and query the element by that? Otherwise how do I get that input's value?

Comment: you cannot use the .data function to read the input boxes if that is what you are trying to do.'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you just want to extract the values entered in the input boxes, you **must** go through jQuery or native DOM. dataTables itself is not aware of any changes made to form input fields, so trying to retrieve the values by `cell().data()` will never work, with or without `id`'s / orthogonal data :

```js
aTable.cell(0,2).nodes().to$().find('input').val()
aTable.cell(0,3).nodes().to$().find('input').val()
```

Will give you the current value of the various inputs. Have replicated your above scenario 100% in this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/obmghyo7/**

This is basically also how the official documentation suggests a way to extract values from form inputs -> **https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html**

If you want to perform filtering / searches within the table, which also includes changes made by the user in form inputs, then it is a little more tricky -> **[JQuery Datatables search within input and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852497/jquery-datatables-search-within-input-and-select/27860934#27860934)** (mine, but I dont know any better answer)

Comment: What davidkonrad said.  But here is another example http://jsbin.com/viqafe/edit?js,output    In this one, I copy the value in the textbox and added it to the associated column.

Comment: I tried to follow the doc example for form data, but could not figure it out; that's quite a jump from "var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();" to what you provided.
I had a (DOM) solution with just normal html tables: "colAchange = aTable.rows[0].cells[2].firstChild.value;" but trying to get that into a 'Datatables' reference isn't clear in the docs.
Answer works perfect, appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Reviewing the docs further, I found the .nodes() reference, but where is the information about .to$() ? I'm not sure what that is doing 'to' the node(s).

Comment: @KJackson **https://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24()** is the same as **https://datatables.net/reference/api/toJQuery()** and it only works on `nodes()` not `node()` [which to me is a lack in dataTables] `to$()` just return the DOM node as a jQuery instance, so you easier can operate on the DOM. It is more easy to use `.find()` than starting to use `querySelector()`.`.if`.. and so on. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sort of hackish yet applicable and simple solution. The thing to note is my code DOES allow usage of the DataTables `data()` method and also that this is more of a solution for anybody receiving HTML code instead of inner text from each cell of a row, rather than trying to get the value of an `input` text box. The row clicked on returns an array through `data()`. Each cell of the row is wrapped in a `span` so any plaintext/non-HTML strings inside a `td` can be rendered as HTML elements and therefore be recognized by the jQuery `text()` method:

```
$('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
   var rowArray = aTable.row(this).data();
   var colAchange = $('<span/>').html(rowArray[0]).text();
   var colBchange = $('<span/>').html(rowArray[1]).text();
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nyv7j6h8/

Answer (score 0):

get data from column 4

```
        var Amount = 0.00
        var t = $('#table').DataTable();
        t.rows().every(function () {
        Amount += parseFloat($(t.cell(this.index(), 4).node()).find('input').val());
         });
```