# Form inputs with Datatables

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables, input-field

I have a Datatable with form inputs.

[image: datatable]

This is how I create it

```
    public function getpurchasedata(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->get('orderID')){
            $id = $request->orderID;
            $orderNo = PurchaseOrder::find($id);
            $order_items = PurchaseOrderItem::where('order_id',$orderNo->order_id)
                                            ->with('material')->get();

            return DataTables::of($order_items)
                    ->addColumn('name',function($order_items){
                            $name = $order_items->material;
                            return $name['name'];
                        })->addColumn ('expdate',function($order_items){
                            return '<input type ="date" id="expdate" 
                                    name="expdate" class="form-control">';
                        })->addColumn('action', function ($order_items) {
                            $buttons ='<button id="edit" 
                                                class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button id="remove" 
                                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                        </button>';

                            return $buttons;
                        })->rawColumns(['expdate','action'])->make(true);

        }
    }
```

I use the following method to pass Data table values to the controller

```
grn_tableData:grn_table.data().toArray(),
```

but when i submit data using an ajax function i get html markups instead on input values for the expdate column. how can i get the real value ? explain me

[image: output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Datatables cell value that is input text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917738/get-datatables-cell-value-that-is-input-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **hidden** column next to your `expdate` column. Doing this, you can get the real value after form submission.