# jQuery Datatables is returning html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables for one project. I applied datatable to an existing table, as shown below:

```
var table = '#datatable-1';
var dataTable = $(table).DataTable({
    'paging'      : true,
    'lengthChange': true,
    'searching'   : true,
    'ordering'    : true,
    'info'        : true,
    'autoWidth'   : false,
    select: {
        style: 'multi'
    }
});
```

Then I iterate over each row of the table, try to get the row content, but I obtained some HTML inside.

```
dataTable.rows({
    order: 'applied',
    page: 'all',
    search: 'applied',
    selected: true
}).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    console.log(this.data());
});
```

[image: This is my like my table sees]

And this is the result after I do a `console.log(this.data())`.

```
Array [ "A &amp; B", "143 AVE", "", "AMAZON", "EU", "", "<textarea name="" rows="1"></textar…" ]
```

Anyone knows how to get the row content like is shown in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over dummy elements to translate html entities by `text()` or extract form input values by `val()` (as I believe you want as well) :

```
table.rows().every(function() {
  var data = this.data();
  data.forEach(function(d, index, arr) {
    d = $('<div>').html(d);
    arr[index] = d.val() || d.text()
  })
  console.log(data)
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ocL7xhzg/**

In your case the array would be logged out as

```
Array [ "A & B", "143 AVE", "", "AMAZON", "EU", "", "" ]
```

Comment: Fix the issue parcial, if you change the text of textarea the new value is not recognize and not show.

Comment: @omixam, **??**, this is how DataTables works. has nothing to do with your question. If you want DataTables internal cache to be updated with changes in form input see this answer -> **https://stackoverflow.com/a/27860934/1407478** it is easy to overcome -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ocL7xhzg/1/**

Comment: you have reason, this is like datatables works. Thanks for the bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You have an Array. You can get first record (A & B) with `this.data()[0]`. Increase array index for next values.

Comment: How you can see above, if I do that I will obtain "A &amp; B" and not "A & B" that is the current value for this position. Also, there is textarea tag shows in the response.